# Why do we need to check string length larger than 0?

Tags: c, string, conditional-statements, cs50, capitalize

I got this example from CS50. I know that we need to check "s == NULL" in case there is no memory in the RAM. But, I am not sure why do we need to check the string length of t before capitalize.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Get a string
    char *s = get_string("s: ");
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate memory for another string
    char *t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (t == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Copy string into memory
    strcpy(t, s);

    // Why do we need to check this condition?
    if (strlen(t) > 0)
    {
        t[0] = toupper(t[0]);
    }

    // Print strings
    printf("s: %s\n", s);
    printf("t: %s\n", t);

    // Free memory
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do we need to use "if (strlen(t) > 0)" before capitalize?

Comment: @ikegami: Consider me surprised, [cs50.h](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/main/src/cs50.h) itself actually states the library destructor will free the allocations from `get_string()`, and indeed it registers its `teardown()` with `atexit()`... so... seems I underestimated CS50. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Based on https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string, there is a line stated that get_string free memory.

Comment: It's just that not freeing all your allocated memory before leaving main is so commonplace...

Answer (score 10):

Conceptually, there is no character to uppercase when the string is empty.

Technically, it's not needed. The first character of an empty string is `0`, and `toupper(0)` is `0`.

---

Note that `strlen(t) > 0` can also be written as `t[0] != 0` or just `t[0]`. There's no need to actually calculate the length of the string to find out if it's an empty string.

Also, make sure to read [chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427264/589924) for a correction regarding signed `char`.

Answer (score 3):

`// Why do we need to check this condition?`

There is **no need** for the check. A *string* of length 0 consists of only a *null character* and `toupper('\0');` returns `'\0'`.

---

**Advanced**: There is a need for something else though.

`char` may act as a *signed* or *unsigned* `char`.  If `t[0] < 0`, (maybe due to entering 'é') then `toupper(negative)` is *undefined behavior* (UB).  `toupper()` is only defined for `EOF`, (some negative) and values in the `unsigned char` range.

A more valuable code change, though pedantic, would be to access the characters as if they were `unsigned char`, then call `toupper()`.

```
// if (strlen(t) > 0) { t[0] = toupper(t[0]); }
t[0] = (char) toupper(((unsigned char*)t)[0]);
// or 
t[0] = (char) toupper(*(unsigned char*)t));
```

Comment: Ah, operator precedence strikes again, I did misunderstand the code. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

For any string `t`, the valid indexes (*of the actual characters in the string*) will be `0` to `strlen(t) - 1`.

Using `strlen(t)` as index will be the index of the null-terminator (assuming that it's a "proper" null-terminated string).

If `strlen(t) == 0` then `t[0]` will be the null-terminator. And doing `toupper` on the null-terminator makes no sense. This is what the check does, make sure that there is at least one actual character (beyond the null-terminator) in the string.

In other words: It check that the string isn't empty.

Comment: As C lib has "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.", the standard does not invalidate the _null character_ as a character of the string.  `'\0'` is included as part of the string, not some appendage to the string.  "the valid indexes (of the characters in the string) will be 0 to strlen(t) - 1" is off by one.  Valid indexes of the characters of a string go up to and include `strlen(t)`.